# Geopandas spatial join not working

Tags: python, geopandas

I have two GeoDataframes - one has polygons, the other points.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
area = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('areas.shp')
print area.crs

{u'lon_0': -91.8666666667, u'datum': u'NAD83', u'y_0': 3000000, u'no_defs': True, u'proj': u'lcc', u'x_0': 6200000, u'units': u'm', u'lat_2': 77, u'lat_1': 49, u'lat_0': 63.390675}
```

Addresses were assigned geolocations through an API, so I assigned a CRS 4326, as that's the one most commonly used it seems.

```
location['geometry'] = location.Geolocation.apply(lambda x: Point(eval(x)))
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(location, geometry='geometry', crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'})
```

Then I changed the area's CRS:

```
area = area.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})
```

And tried to merge the two dataframes

```
merged = gpd.sjoin(area, gdf, op='intersects')
```

But the result it gives me is Empty GeoDataFrame. I am not sure why, because the points definitely do fall inside polygons. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my files

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9lioawgsor5y4wc/AABkaaFpjAjisQEVaLrFwSnsa?dl=0

I suspect that its because of the points that were somehow not properly processed into the right coordinate system maybe.

Comment: Have you tried plotting them to make sure they overlap? http://geopandas.org/mapping.html#maps-with-layers

Comment: If you can post some sample data perhaps?

Comment: @BERA, I have, the points for some reason are not plotting right, that probably is my problem there.

Comment: @om_henners, I just added them to the original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your data, the issue is in the property points that you've geocoded:

```
|                     Property Address |               Geolocation |                      geometry |
|--------------------------------------|---------------------------|-------------------------------|
| 1586 LORNE ST E,  Kamloops BC Canada | (50.673675,  -120.298973) | POINT (50.673675 -120.298973) |
```

When you've geocoded the addresses you've got latitude and longitude, which is fine, but you've created the points in that order. Latitude and Longitude are Y, X measures respectively. You'll have to swap the coordinates when you create the points in your Geolocation (and doing so works fine in terms of the spatial join).

Comment: Thank you for spotting that, I would've never guessed that is where the mistake was. But now I'm facing a problem with swapping the coordinates. Below is the script I wrote that is for some reason not functioning. for u in gdf['Geolocation']:
    u = u.replace('(', '')
    u = u.replace(')', '')
    a, b = u.split(',')
    correct = [b, a]
    correct = gdf['Geolocation_correct']